# How to multiply two sparse matrix using cuSparse?

Tags: cuda, gpu, sparse-matrix

cuSparse only has a function api for multiplying a sparse matrix with a dense matrix. How to do multiply operation for two sparse matrices using cuSparse or any other cuda liberary?

Comment: What about cusp? http://code.google.com/p/cusp-library/

Comment: Can you update the link to the actual function showing multiplication of two sparse matrices ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented, the [CUSP library](http://cusplibrary.github.io/) is available for matrix multiplication. From the site:

> Cusp is a library for sparse linear algebra and graph computations on CUDA. Cusp provides a flexible, high-level interface for manipulating sparse matrices and solving sparse linear systems.

Answer (score 8):

The current version of cuSPARSE (CUDA Toolkit v5.0) supports sparse matrix-sparse matrix multiplications using the [cusparse<t>csrgemm functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#topic_9_2).

For this routine, compute capability 2.0 or better is needed.